# airodump-ng -d returns nothing

Tags: aircrack-ng, airodump-ng

I am using Kali Linux on VMWare Fusion on my Mac.

I am able to airodump and see my router, but when I run `airodump-ng -d BSSID` to see devices connecting to the network, then connect my phone, nothing shows up.

I ran `airodump-ng check kill` and then I put my usb adapter into monitor mode.

I am using `Alpha AWUS36NHA`.

Comment: Welcome to the community, you sure the chip driver is supported and loaded? I think you can run `lsusb` and `lsmod` to find out.

Comment: Yes it's working properly, I'm able to do all kinds of stuff with it like packet sniffing, rogue ap, and mitm attacks.